# How to leave a queue of programs to run in Spyder 3.3.0+?

Tags: spyder, jobs, queuing

I used to be able to simply press run on the different programs on the Editor and the programs would show on the History Log and stay in a queue to run serially once the current program was done, since I updated from 3.6.1 to 3.6.6 i can't seem to do that anymore. I do not want to run separate instances(plenty of answers on that) I just want to leave jobs to run serially as I used to be able to, pls Help if anyone knows the answer, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This functionality was removed in our **3.3.0** version, due to [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7293).

As a matter of fact, we never intended for our consoles to queue jobs sequentially because it's not possible to stop them all at once.

Comment: Thank you, for clarifying it. Anyhow it was quite useful. Maybe you guys want to think of a way to be able to queue jobs being able to stop them.